# How long does AWS Cognito ForgotPassword verification code last?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am implementing a "Forgot Password" feature for an application that uses AWS Cognito.

AWS will send an email and/or SMS to the email registered for a user with a verification code that is used to reset the password.

I am wondering if anyone knows how long the code that is sent out is valid for, and whether or not this is configurable? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code validity can be obtained from Quotas in Amazon Cognito Section.

The Forgot password code has a validity of 1 hour and this quota is non-adjustable. So you can not change it.

Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

[image]